# Regarding Kentico 9 site deployment on Azure

Tags: kentico

I want to deploy Kentico 9 site on Azure and want to use shared file system for my media content, can you please suggest which Azure configuration (Azure Cloud Services or Azure Web Apps) I should referred?

Answer (score 1):

I'd highly recommend going with Web App over Cloud Services.  Mainly because Web App is almost like running on a regular server where Cloud Services is quite a bit different and harder to work with in my opinion.

Check this article out regarding some issues with Kentico and Azure Blog storage as well as how to setup your storage provider to only store media files.

http://www.kehrendev.com/blog/brenden-kehren/may-2016/problems-with-azure-and-kentico

Answer (score 0):

Could you describe what do you mean by *shared file system for my media content*?

From my experience - it`s (a little bit) easier to deploy (and maintain) Kentico to Azure Web Apps but they do not provide so many customizations - in my humble opinion - the biggest one is you are not able to connect via remote desktop (but this is supported by *Azure Cloud Services*).

Please note - if you are using *Cloud Services* you must use *Azure Blob Storage* - [source](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Microsoft+Azure+web+hosting+options) - which could be in conflict with your requirements.

You can find more information about *Web App*s vs *Cloud Service*s vs *Virtual Machines* on the mentioned page.

TL;DR; - if you do not need customizations, remote desktop and startup tasks - go for *WebApps*. If not, try to specify more requirements.

You can also check comparinson of the technologies from the Microsoft`s point of view [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/choose-web-site-cloud-service-vm/).

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear who you want to share the media with...

If you want to share the assets amongst more Kentico instances or with a 3rd party system, I'd probably use the Azure Blob Storage. Kentico comes with a dedicated [file provider](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Configuring+file+system+providers) for this exact use out of the box. It's called `CMS.AzureStorage`.

Using the blob storage is not a limiting factor in terms of hosting your app. You can still use all available options: Web Apps, VM or Cloud Service. There are some technical implications, of course. But they're all described in the [documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Azure+Web+Apps+problematic+folders).

I recommend checking the [comparison matrix](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K9/Microsoft+Azure+web+hosting+options) to find a hosting option that suits your need best. Kentico recommends using App Service (Web Apps) for most projects as it's easiest to maintain. However, you can't use certain features like Kentico Windows services, for instance. Question is, do you really need them?